# adjustViewBounds gives wrong width - Android

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to display an image which will have the width of the parent view and the height will be calculated to keep the aspect ratio.

The problem is that the width of the image expands beyond parent view width, like the image is zoomed.

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
     android:id="@+id/imageview_mainimage"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
/>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: change scale type to `fitStart` will fix for you.

Comment: Didn't work ...

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your SimpleDraweeView doesn't have the same aspect ratio as your loaded image, and adding `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`will make the SimpleDraweeView try to load the content cropping the image to best fit the smallest of the 2 dimensions. You can either expect the image to have a certain ratio `fresco:viewAspectRatio="1.33"`, or use a different option for scaleType

Comment: I used all scaleTypes with no results. fresco:viewAspectRatio="1.33" worked, but in some images it doesn't fit exactly the width. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: your "fresco:viewAspectRatio" value should be according to your needs :), 1.33 must be computed to match your loaded picture's aspect ratio. Compute it from your picture's resolution w/h or h/w

Comment: There isn't any xml only solution?

Comment: only if all your pictures have the same aspect ratio. In that case you can compute it manually and just set the value in the xml. Otherwise you'll have to set that parameter at runtime